# Import issues in Python

Tags: python, import

I've been getting into Python after 20 years of c# and c++. The whole importing mechanics still seems weird to me, and there's a lot of conflicting posts and guides about it. I decided to make a short little project using a DDD approach and use quite a bit of references to other modules in order to really understand how it SHOULD be done.

My project structure is as follows:

[image]

I just made the library folder to store a bunch of helper classes/functions. I just started adding a valueobject base class for all valueobjects. For now, it's extremely simple:

[image]

The bounded_contexts folder just contains 2 folders, 1 for account_management, 1 for customer_management. In the domain folder for customer_management, I created a folder for the customers aggregate. In there, I just want to create a simple housenumber valueobject:

[image]

Since I want to refer to the valueobject baseclass in library/domain/, I need to perform an import in housenumber.py. I tried several things (even without having the **init**.py files, since some sources say it's not mandatory anymore), but nothing seems to do the trick...
Some attempts with the error messages it gives me:
[image]

[image]

I really wonder what the once-and-for-all CORRECT way is to do this. Obviously, I will not run housenumber.py by itself, so the "h1 = HouseNumber(15, "b")" line is just in there to see if I could get it to work. Is there 1 single way to get this to work while testing something in housenumber.py itself, and also later to run the entire project (like an api that I'll build in the customer_management/api and account_management/api folders?

Since Python has this "there's only one correct way to do things" philosophy behind it, it stumps me that it's so hard to find a clear-cut answer... This being said: I'm quite new to bigger projects in Python, so bear with me ;-) Any help and constructive criticism would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i prefer modify your init.py instead of dot to direct into your file

Comment: Agreed, adding some imports in __init__.py is cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the following worked: simply disable the PyLint extension as there is apparently a bug in it. I use the Flake8 linter now, which runs just fine. No more red squigglies:
[image]

And working code:

[image]

Thank you for the effort and time everybody! I almost switched to another IDE out of sheer frustration since adding

> "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}${pathSeparator}${env:PYTHONPATH}"

to the launch.json worked fine and made my code run perfectly, but the "unable to import" notification from PyLint remained whatever I did. In the end, I did switch to Flake8 and disabled the PyLint extension, and everything worked perfectly. Hopefully that helps other people that have a similar issue in VSCode. There's an issue in GitHub, reported late November, that is about this exact issue, so they are aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get a `No module named 'library'` error is that among the directory paths that python searches for when trying to do your import, there is no module / directory named `'library'`. This can be fixed by adding the parent directory of `library` to the `sys.path` for the import to work as expected, `bounded_contexts` in this case (I understand that `library` is inside `bounded_contexts`).

This can be done as follows.
As you are running `housenumber.py` module, in this module obtain the path of `bounded_contexts` and add it to `sys.path` so as python sees this directory when trying to perform the import.

```
import os
import sys

bounded_contexts_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(bounded_contexts_path)

from libary.domain.valueobject import ValueObject
```

We simply try to obtain `bounded_contexts_path` by going one level up from `__file__` module multiple times (the `housenumber.py` module you are running.)

Note: There may more optimal ways of doing it, but this is surely one of the ways.

Comment: I've seen that done several times, but many people seem to think it's a bit hacky and not ideal. I have to agree with that. This seems not to be quite clean. Does work though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a `main.py` file in the root of the project and import whatever nested scripts you want to test there.

For example, consider this directory structure:

```bash
➜  test-project tree
.
├── bounded_contexts
│   └── customer_management
│       └── domain
│           └── customers
│               └── housenumber.py
├── library
│   ├── domain
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── valueobject.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── main.py

6 directories, 5 files
```

Here's `main.py`:

```py
import bounded_contexts.customer_management.domain.customers.housenumber
```

Here's `housenumber.py`:

```py
from library.domain.valueobject import ValueObject

print(ValueObject)
```

When I run `main.py`, everything works fine:

```bash
➜  test-project python main.py 
<class 'library.domain.valueobject.ValueObject'>
```

Trying to run the nested file does not:

```bash
➜  test-project python bounded_contexts/customer_management/domain/customers/housenumber.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/junk/test-project/bounded_contexts/customer_management/domain/customers/housenumber.py", line 1, in <module>
    from library.domain.valueobject import ValueObject
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'library'
```

I think this is because the interpreter can't find the modules above the executing module when you execute the nested module directly.

Comment: That does indeed work, however, the actual projects that will run will be in the api folders of the respective bounded contexts, as they will be microservices. Each of them will of course use the library packages. The example you sent does indeed work, but when there is a main.py file sitting inside bounded_contexts/customer_management/api for example, it's back to the same error, since I would have to go and find modules above the executing module...

Comment: After some experimentation, running this from the project root folder does work: python -m bounded_contexts.customer_management.domain.customers.housenumber